# how do I build a layout that resizes dynamically in java?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I need to know how to build a java layout that will be dynamically resized.  The layout is set up with 4 panels, stacked top to bottom:

the top panel is a GridLayout(4,2).  each rown is a label and a text field
the second panel is a single button
the third panel is a grid layout (n,2).  I will get to n in a minute
the bottom panel is also a single button

the n is a dynamically changing number.  the third panel contains a text field, then a panel with 2 buttons to the right.  the problem I have is that I need to be able to add and remove these rows and have the JFrame resize automatically as I do.  I tried setting the Frame as a GridLayout(4,1), but when I change the size on actionPerformed(), it spreads the extra space evenly.  I want to add only space to the third panel.

Thanks

**EDIT: ActionPerformed Method**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object src = e.getSource();

    if (src == addTarget) {
        targetChoosers.add(new JFileChooser(new File("C:\\")));
        targets.add(new JTextField());
        targetButtons.add(new JButton("Browse..."));
        targetDeleters.add(new JButton("Delete"));

        int numTargets = targets.size();
        targetButtons.get(numTargets - 1).addActionListener(this);
        targetDeleters.get(numTargets - 1).addActionListener(this);

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numTargets, 2));
        bottomPanel.add(targets.get(numTargets - 1));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        panel.add(targetButtons.get(numTargets - 1));
        panel.add(targetDeleters.get(numTargets - 1));

        bottomPanel.add(panel);
    } 

    //...

    else if (targetDeleters.contains(src)) {
        int index = targetDeleters.indexOf(src);

        targets.remove(index);
        targetChoosers.remove(index);
        targetButtons.remove(index);
        targetDeleters.remove(index);

        this.remove(submit);
        this.remove(bottomPanel);

        int numTargets = targets.size();
        bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(numTargets, 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++) {
            bottomPanel.add(targets.get(i));

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            panel.add(targetButtons.get(i));
            panel.add(targetDeleters.get(i));

            bottomPanel.add(panel);
        }

        this.add(bottomPanel);
        this.add(submit);
    }

    //...   

    pack();

    invalidate();
    validate();
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows how you invoke  `pack()` in your button listener.

Comment: @trashgod I have posted the actionperformed method (the relevant parts anyway).  I'm not sure how pack() will help, as GridLayout automatically sets the sizes of the components to be evenly spread throughout the frame

Comment: @ewok then post here runnable code based on SSCCE and then you'll see lots of miracles with layout :-)

Comment: @mKorbel my fully runnable code is about 45 kloc. I do not believe that I can post it.

Comment: Note that an SSCCE is not your 'fully runnable code'.  Please actually *read* the document on the SSCCE.

Comment: I interpreted "have the `JFrame` resize automatically" to mean [`pack()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29), which "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) may help for the (n,2) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another great LayoutManager is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I can't write so many lines because  [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)  is a library and how can i explain a library.